# jquery datepicker date +1 is adding 10 days

Tags: jquery

I have following code

```
$("#in").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        dateText = new Date(dateText);
        dateText = dateText.getDate()+1;
        $('#out').datepicker("option", 'minDate', dateText);
    }
});
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ANYTA/1/

However, the `out` datepicker is adding 10 days instead of 1 day. What could be modified to make it work as intended? thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dateText = dateText.setDate(dateText.getDate()+1);
```

---

**NOTE**

```
somedate.setDate(days);
```

1. ***days*** is integer
2. Expected values are ***1-31***, but other values are allowed:

2.1) 0 will result in the last hour of the previous month

2.1) -1 will result in the hour before the last hour of the previous month

3. when month has 31 days, then 32 will result in the first day of the next month
4. If month has 30 days then, 32 will result in the second day of the next month

---

Your code shoule

```
$("#in").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
       var actualDate = new Date(dateText);
       var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate()+1);
        $('#out').datepicker('option', 'minDate', newDate );
    }
});

$("#out").datepicker();
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ANYTA/4/)**

Comment: hi, your solution makes all date is selectable even before the min date, the fiddle is here, the original one, jsfiddle.net/ANYTA/1 however, when replaced with your code, every date is selectedable.

Comment: hi, it still add 10 days instead of 1 day

Comment: @cicakman check my update answer and fiddle and I think its perfect now

Comment: good, full, step-by-step answer answer, easy to follow, demo; +1 for this nice piece of work

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I have searched and searched and your method was the most intuitive and easy to understand!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
dateText.setDate(dateText.getDate() + 1);
```

getDate returns a 1-31 day of the month, so adding one to it doesn't make sense.

setDate sets the day of the month, so if you add one day to the day of the month, you're effectively adding one day.

(Also, setDate is smart enough to handle rollovers, i.e. 31 Jan + 1 == 1 Feb)

Comment: hi, your solution makes all date is selectable even before the min date, the fiddle is here, the original one, http://jsfiddle.net/ANYTA/1/ however, when replaced with your code, every date is selectedable.

Comment: hi Corbin, thanks so much for helping me, but it still says the same as previous solution. thank you

Comment: No need to create a new date.  Just a wild guess, but I bet you left the assignment in.  http://jsfiddle.net/ANYTA/5/

Comment: Very good answer, i wish i could select your both answers as correct one. Thank you so much for help.